# How can I use .cshtml and .html files with Durandal

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, durandal

I started using DurandalJs framework with asp.net MVC. It's working perfect.

But now I need to use .cshtml files as views for durandal. So I added to root web.config

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

But DurandalJs still try to get .html files as views.

So I correct viewEngine.js file:

```
    return {
    viewExtension: '.cshtml',
    viewPlugin: 'text',
```

but now DurandalJs  required that all views files should have ".cshtml" extension.

So could I use ".html" and ".cshtml" files together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In main.js I added row:

```
viewLocator.useConvention('viewmodels', 'ViewsProxy/GetView?name=', 'ViewsProxy/GetView?name=');
```

And implemented ViewsProxyController like below:

```
public class ViewsProxyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetView(string name)
    {
        string viewRelativePath = GetRelativePath(name);
        string viewAbsolutePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(viewRelativePath);

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(viewAbsolutePath))
        {
            viewAbsolutePath = ReplaceHtmlWithCshtml(viewAbsolutePath);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(viewAbsolutePath))
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.SetIsHtmlView(name, false);
                viewRelativePath = ReplaceHtmlWithCshtml(viewRelativePath);
                return PartialView(viewRelativePath);
            }
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }

        FilePathResult filePathResult = new FilePathResult(viewAbsolutePath, "text/html");
        return filePathResult;
    }

    private string ReplaceHtmlWithCshtml(string path)
    {
        string result = Regex.Replace(path, @"\.html$", ".cshtml");
        return result;
    }

    private string GetRelativePath(string name)
    {
        string result = string.Format("{0}{1}", AppConfigManager.DurandalViewsFolder, name);
        return result;
    }
}
```

So now durandal application can work with .html and .cshtml.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your routes to accept cshtml as the extensions for MVC routes.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}.cshtml",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", namespaces: new string[] { "PAWS.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

Also you need to make sure your application pool is running under integrated and not classic.

But I don't recommend doing this.  You should try and not have the server render any of your HTML.  The reason for this is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554919/how-to-use-partial-views-with-durandal-js-mvc3/15559466#15559466)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Durandal `viewEngine` and `viewLocator` customizations that allows to use both local '.html' and remote '.cshtml' views simultaneously.

[Is it possible to have multiple viewEngine.viewExtension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15488743/347309)